# How to extract all necessarily code for a function?

Tags: functions, packages, variable-definitions, symbols, downvalues

Many times when someone pastes a piece of code into SE there are missing values and symbols that the user left out.

To prevent this I'm looking for a function that uproots other functions (extract the roots of the function like pulling a plant up from the ground).

I thought there might be something in GeneralUtilities or in some other developer packages...

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost with your botanical metaphor. Could you try to explain further?

Comment: Sorry it's spring and I have plants on my mind... I'll add a concrete example.

Comment: Essentially talking about a dependency tree for a piece of code

Comment: Have you tried `DumpSave["filename.mx"]` without supplying a second argument?

Comment: I am dealing with the same issue, while using DumpSave. I did try DumpSave but it does not seem to accept a single argument, at least on MMA 10.2.

Answer (score 4):

I think `Save` is the built-in function that come closest to what you are looking for.

```
a = 5; n = 1/2;
f[x_] := a + x^2

Save["stdout", f]
```

[image: result]

Comment: What it f relied on a function g which relied on a function h in package i?

Comment: You could try it and see what happens. You could reflect on the fact that definitions of `Plus` and `Power` don't show up.